# Get iteration number in for...of loop while iterating over an object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, ecmascript-2016

I am getting the following object from API call:

```
{
    "email": ["The email has already been taken."],
    "profile_image": [ "profile image is requried." ]
}
```

I used the following code to iterate over this object *(using for...of)*:

```
let message = "";
for (const [error_name, error_value, i] of Object.entries(
  error.response.data.errors
)) {
  message += `${i}: ${error_value[0]}\n`;
}
```

But I am getting `undefined` instead of getting the value of `i`. I want to get the **iteration number**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Object.entries returns a 2d array, where the inner arrays represent key-value pairs (`[key, value]`), so you can't destructure a value `i` which isn't in this inner-array

Comment: Why are you not just using forEach or map or even better reduce?

Comment: You can use `.entries()` to get indices in a for..of loop

Comment: @JonasWilms like `error_value.entries()`???

Comment: `for const [index, [error_name, error_value]] of Object.entries(
  error.response.data.errors
).entries())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Object.entries` item will only contain two values: the key and the value. If you want the index as well, you'll have to implement it yourself or use another strategy. One option is use `forEach` to iterate over the array instead (the second argument `forEach` takes is the current index):

```
let message = "";
Object.entries(error.response.data.errors)
  .forEach(([error_name, error_value], i) => {
    message += `${i}: ${error_value[0]}\n`;
  });
```

You can also avoid the `let` for `message` by using `.map`/`.join`:

```
const message = Object.entries(error.response.data.errors)
  .map(([error_name, error_value], i) => `${i}: ${error_value[0]}`)
  .join('\n');
```

(unlike your original code, this will not have a trailing newline at the end, but that's probably a good thing)

Comment: Bro can you tell me if there is only 1 element in the object then don't display `${i}:` part.

Comment: I'd save the entries in a variable and use the conditional operator. `const message = errorEntries.length === 1 ? errorEntries[1] : entries.map(...code in answer...)`

Comment: Bro the 3rd param is the obj which get passed I wrote, `const message = Object.entries(error.response.data.errors)
                .map(([error_name, error_value], index, obj) =>
                  Object.keys(obj).length == 1
                    ? ${error_value[0]}
                    : ${index + 1}: ${error_value[0]}
                )
                .join("\n");`

Comment: Much better to save the entries in a variable first, rather than to try to stuff it all into a single assignment expression

Answer (score 0):

The iterator from `Object.entries` only produces two-place arrays in the form `[key, value]`. There is no third entry in those arrays.

In general, objects should be considered unordered, so it's not clear why you want an index. But if you do, since you're building a string with concatenation, you could use `map` on the `Object.entries` array instead:

```
let message =
    Object.entries(error.response.data.errors)
    .map(([error_name, error_value], i) => `${i}: ${error_value[0]}\n`)
    .join("");
```

Live Example:

```js
const error = {
    response: {
        data: {
            errors: {
              "email": ["The email has already been taken."],
              "profile_image": [ "profile image is requried." ]
            }
        }
    }
};
let message =
    Object.entries(error.response.data.errors)
    .map(([error_name, error_value], i) => `${i}: ${error_value[0]}\n`)
    .join("");
console.log(message);
```